# FadeTo() on this selection (cloned and appended) not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-effects

I'm new to jQuery and i'd like to `fadeTo()` this selection to give user feedback about data being fetched from the server:

```
// Loop on each array of object returned from the ajax call
$.each(v, function(i, obj) {
   current.find('.key:first').parent()
      .clone(true).appendTo(current)
         .find('.key').text(obj.key).andSelf();
};
```

I've tryed (without success) adding `fadeIn('slow', 1)` call after `appendTo(current)`.

Comment: What does it do exactly ? Does it appear at once or does it not appear at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm guessing, your content appears straight up and you wish it'd fade in.

You need to hide the cloned element before appending to the "current" element. Try this :

```
$.each(v, function(i, obj) {
   current.find('.key:first').parent()
      .clone(true).hide(1).appendTo(current).fadeIn('slow')
         .find('.key').text(obj.key).andSelf();
};
```